# Page Loads but Uninitialized Constant in Controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, runtime-error, rails-routing

ok I have this class; the page loads and everything.

```
class HumanResources::AttendancePerformance::AttendancesController < HumanResources::AttendancePerformanceController

  def index
    query = generic_table_aggregated_queries('attendances','attendances.created_at')
    begin
      @attendances = Attendance
                         .includes(employee: [:actor])
                         .joins(employee: [:actor])
                         .where("actors.name LIKE ? OR " +
                                    "attendances.id LIKE ? OR " +
                                    "attendances.timein LIKE ? OR " +
                                    "attendances.timeout LIKE ? OR " +
                                    "attendances.remark LIKE ? OR " +
                                    "attendances.updated_at LIKE ? OR " +
                                    "attendances.created_at LIKE ?",
                                "%#{query[:search_field]}%",
                                "%#{query[:search_field]}%",
                                "%#{query[:search_field]}%",
                                "%#{query[:search_field]}%",
                                "%#{query[:search_field]}%",
                                "%#{query[:search_field]}%",
                                "%#{query[:search_field]}%")
                         .order(query[:order_parameter] + ' ' + query[:order_orientation])
      @attendances = Kaminari.paginate_array(@attendances).page(params[:page]).per(query[:current_limit])
    rescue => ex
      flash[:general_flash_notification] = "Error has Occured" + ex.to_s
    end
    render 'human_resources/attendance_performance/attendances/index'
  end
```

Yep I know its a bit long; just to make sure I did not miss everything, I am certain error is around here but I cannot find so. The page loads. I just dont know where and why is it saying

```
uninitialized constant HumanResources::AttendancePerformance::AttendancesController::Attendance
```

I presume its the "Attendance" model but it has always worked before... Where is the error? Does it have something to do with the naming of the model and the controller being similar?

Comment: try use `@attendances = ::Attendance` in action

Comment: SOLVED! Why does that work?? what was the "::" for?? @OlegSobchuk

Comment: model `::Attendance` will be searched global

Comment: if it helped you, please mark it as helpful (click flag and up arrow).

Comment: i already did click up arrow. but the flag means for "Serious Problems and Moderation Attention".